# Using oldstyle numbers in XeLaTeX math mode for ONLY inline math

Tags: math-mode, xetex, inline, oldstylenums, mathspec

Is there any way to use OldStyle numbers for text and inline math only, while using Lining in the align and equation environments? Ideally via mathspec, but I'm open to other solutions.